# Display SVG while only setting parent height

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG set in a container like so:

```html
<div style="height: 24px;">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="50%" fill="blue"/>
    <rect x="0" y="50%" width="100%" height="50%" fill="green"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

As you can see the SVG ignores the height set by the container. If I only set a width on the container - it's fine...

The container must only have a height set as the SVG can have a variable width. With display: flex it seems to work, but with other display types it doesn't - so I'm trying to understand why the different display properties work.

Comment: `svg { height:100%; }`?

Comment: I suppose display: flex works because it sets the child's height to be 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This CSS will make the SVG respect the container's height:

```
svg {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: I wonder why this isn't the default option

Comment: @daggett why should it be? Just because you want it to stretch to the height of the container in this particular instance, doesn't mean that is what everyone everywhere would need all the time.

Comment: I thought the whole point of viewBox was to control height and scaling, but it doesn't really in practice - be default the SVG looks to scale to the max width/height. Just seems more logical for SVGs to have a fixed size by default

Comment: @daggett Not quite. The point of `viewBox` is to say what part of the SVG is the important part. Thus, *when the SVG is given a width and height*, the renderer fills that area with the elements within the `viewBox`. That way, the SVG can be scaled like any other image, always displaying the same content.

Comment: ...and if you want to give the SVG a default size, use its `width` and `height` attributes.

Comment: Gotcha. I guess I'm still wondering why setting a width reacts differently, feels inconsistent

Comment: Historical reasons :) HTML layout always started with **width**. Either an element has a specified width, or it gets all the available width of its container (as in your case). Then, when the width is taken care of, each element claims as much vertical space (*height*) as it needs (even if that is taller than the container, again as in your case). The newer `flexbox` and `grid` layouts are more clever in how they work and give you more control.